# Error while trying to attach .mdf to a SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, ssms

The snapshot says is it all - I used to be able to attach a database, but after i detached today then tried to attach, i kept getting this error:

[http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/2574/attacht.jpg http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/2574/attacht.jpg](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/2574/attacht.jpg)

http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/2574/attacht.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 5 means Access Denied. The account running SQL Server has no access to the file GMATech.mdf. Grant the necessary rights:

```
cacls "c:\Program...\GMATech.mdf" /E /G SQLServerMSSQLUser$<hostname>$<instancename>:F
```

where hostname is the name of the mahcine running SQL and instancename is the name of the SQL instance (MSSQLSERVER for default instance).